# Can Spectator Ions Affect Reaction Kinetics?

Tags: kinetics

Specifically, I am interested in the reaction of different hydroxides (in aqueous form) with $\ce{CO_2}$. I would like to determine which hydroxide would conduct the reaction the fastest. My initial thought would be that spectator ions would have no effect, and since the concentration of the hydroxide has a direct relationship with the reaction rate, therefore the most soluble hydroxides would react the fastest.

However, after seeing [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed1001703), I am confused as to whether spectator ions affect reaction rate or not. The abstract mentions "halide-acceleration effect," so I don't think the principle would apply to hydroxides, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I don't know an answer here, but I just wanted to say that if "spectator" ions do have a big effect, then "spectator ion" isn't a good name for them.  (That doesn't mean the name isn't widely used; it just means, like many things in science, that the name doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: Without more specific information on the exact experimental setup it is impossible to speculate. However in "book problems" the real chemistry is oft ignored because the math is miserable. So to simplify the math concentrations are used in rate and equilibrium formulas instead of activities.  Concentrations should only be exchangeable for activities in very dilute solutions.

Comment: The initial premise "spectator ions would have no effect" is wrong.  Spectator ions do have effect. The term "spectator ion" means it is not involved in a reaction directly. But it has indirect effects, affecting e.g. solvation of other ions, ionic strength, relative permeability, viscosity, ion mobility, solubility, reaction kinetics etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Everything present has an effect. The question is, is it distinguishable and measurable? Your proposal has many variables to consider; here are some. The amount of hydroxide, analysis by formulation or by titration, Activity of OH-, a good pH meter can help here, solubility of the hydroxide, carbonate, and bicarbonate; even the viscosity of the solutions. You will think up some more.

You intend to study the effect of different hydroxides in reacting with CO2. Since the differences are the counter-ions they will most likely have an effect. You will determine what the effect is and its importance. [avoid adding any halides]

There is much in the literature about this, check some out, a fresh look can be important.;

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be ions. Think of the familiar ammonia/hydrogen chloride experiment where you introducecthese gases at opposolite ends of the tube, and they diffuse towards each other until they meet and react somewhere in the "middle" (actually towards the HCl end due to the lighter ammonia molecules diffusing faster). This process is slowed down if you put "inert" nitrogen gas into the tube because of the impact of the obstructing nitrogen molecules on the diffusion process.